# как убрать сотые в рандоме

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

мне нужно убрать числа после запятых
например: было 1 281,4453125 , стало 1 281

Comment: Int или юзать randint

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код для генерации случайного числа. Без него лучшее что можно - это округлить до целого. Но как будет округляться - влияет на результат.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
 
number = random.randint(20, 35) #тут надо писать те число в диапазоне которых будет выбрано случайное число
print(number)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).